# VS 2010: Disable Fileheader for new class files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I recently noticed that Visual Studio 2010 (Professional) inserts a FileHeader automatically in new class files. I don't know when this started but some time ago this wasn't enabled. Also, since then the using directives are added after the namespace.

This is the way the file looks like after generation:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="Class1.cs" company="Microsoft">
// TODO: Update copyright text.
// </copyright>
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyNamespace
{
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;

   /// <summary>
   /// TODO: Update summary.
   /// </summary>
   public class Class1
   {
   }
}
```

And thats the way it should look like (and how I want it):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace
{
   public class Class1
   {
   }
}
```

I disabled all extensions and all plugins, but the problem stays. Hopefully anyone here can tell my how to restore the previoous behaviour.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual studio uses templates to generate new files. You can read about how to create your own templates here http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/how-to-fix-visual-studio-file-templates/. The default templates are commonly stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates and it is these you'll want to edit if you want to globally replace the format.

Comment: I just checked that folder and all my old templates were saved as .bak files. I replaced the actual ones by the backups. Had to reset my Visual Studio some weeks ago, perhaps the new templates were installed then.

Comment: Just want to add that you have to run devenv.exe /installvstemplates to update the ItemTemplatesCache

Answer (score 1):

For me the file headers showed up after installing `Resharper` and `Stylecop`.

To get rid of them I disabled the header inclusions in `Resharper` (Code Cleanup section) and also made sure the file header rules are no longer enforced in `StyleCop`. Next I modified the file templates stimms mentioned earlier. And finally I had to run **devenv.exe /installvstemplates** from the command line for Visual Studio to register the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a ReSharper thing,  Check your ReSharper settings.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Usage_Scenarios__Configuring_and_Inserting_a_Default_File_Header.html

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/12/automating-file-header-information-with-resharper/

Comment: I disabled ReSharper and the file header was still inserted. Also I have no file header configured in ReSharper options (just checked that).

Comment: Same here - very irritating. I think it might be to do with stylecop integration